# JSON Schema to HTML form in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, schema

I would like to generate a HTML form out of JSON schema in Ruby. Can anyone help me out how this can be done ? or do we have any library to accomplish this?

The whole idea is, the inputted JSON Schema with elements should be converted to a HTML form.

```
{  
   "$schema": "json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
   "title": "A boolean",
   "description": "A simple boolean data type as schema root",
   "type": "boolean"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON?

Comment: {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
  "title": "A boolean",
  "description": "A simple boolean data type as schema root",
  "type": "boolean"
}

This is just a simple.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be possible to create a form out of ANY JSON schema. IF you have created some format, you can create the form out of it.

For example,

```
json = [
    {
        "name": "Book Name",
        "type": "integer",
        "is_required": true,
        "placeholder": "Closed Deals"
    },
    {
        "name": "No of Pages",
        "field_type": "date",
        "is_required": true,
        "placeholder": "Enter time spent in minutes"
    },
    {
        "name": "Published On",
        "type": "date",
        "unit": "date",
        "placeholder": "Date"
    }
]
```

Now we need to iterate through the data and create the form:

```
<%= form_for <your_model> %>
   <% json.each do |field_data| %>
     <%= f.text_field field_data['name'], type: field_data['field_type'], required: field_data['is_required'], placeholder: field_data['placeholder'] %>
   <% end %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I customize the form builder helpers to make this loop dynamic? i.e the helper need to handle generating the form elements based on the JSON data say., which you have mentioned.

Comment: You can do it using something like [this](https://coderwall.com/p/-biuug/custom-form-builders-in-rails). If you want to keep it simple then I think that view helper or partial would do the job.